# Google places, strictbounds with type regions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api, google-places

I am attempting to return autocomplete results limited to a type of regions -

> the (regions) type collection instructs the Places service to return
>   any result matching the following types: 
>    - locality
>    - sublocality
>    - postal_code
>    - country
>    - administrative_area_level_1
>    - administrative_area_level_2

[https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete][1]

but also locked to a strictbounds around the EU. When I use type (cities) this same code works. When I change the type to regions it drops the strict bounds. Is regions incompatible with strictbounds? Am I missing something silly? Also dropping the region:'EU' param does nothing.

```
function setup_autocomplete(){

        //console.log( 'setting up autocomplete' );
        //setbounds around EU
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({ center: new google.maps.LatLng( 54.0000, -4.0000 ), radius: 60000 });

        var input = document.getElementById('home-carousel-location-input') || false,
            options = {
                region:'EU',
                types: ['(regions)'],
                bounds: circle.getBounds(), 
                strictbounds: true 

            }, autocomplete;

        if( input ){

            autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your Places Autocomplete implementation is not quite correct as you are using the `region:` parameter which is not supported. Here is the list of [supported options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#AutocompleteOptions) that can be set on an Autocomplete object.

You can remove the `region:` parameter. You can set the region restrictions by using `strictbounds:` and `bounds:` parameter.

```
autocomplete.setOptions({
    strictBounds: true,
    bounds: circle.getBounds(),
    types: ['(regions)']
});
```

You can try the sample jsbin demo [here](https://jsbin.com/cubepugore/edit?html,js,output).

In the demo, I've set a `fillColor:` to the circle to visualize the radius and added a rectangle with also a `fillColor:` to visualize the strictbounds. The Places Autocomplete service will return any result matching the `(regions)` [type](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_types) within the bounds.